# Set multiple content type in handling get request

Tags: java, http

I have created a http server which handles the request and send JSON as well as exe file as response to the get request. So can we set multiple content types in one request?

```
Headers h = new Headers();
h = t.getResponseHeaders();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("version", dirFiles.lastEntry().getKey());
String output = json.toString(); // I want to send this with response
File file = new File(fileName);
h.add("CONTENT-TYPE", "application/octet-stream");
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int count = 0;
while ((count = fs.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
fs.close();
os.close();
```

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible as per standard.

Comment: i.e. we cannot set like h.add("Content-type","application/json"); h.add("content-type","application/octet-stream"); or any other way?

Comment: Don't attempt to do this in one shot. Use two different requests. One upon the success of previous.

Comment: But i have to do this in one shot,basically i need to download a file as well as i need json data at client side in one shot

Comment: Why do you have to do this in 'one shot'? What kind of server is accepting a JSON body in a GET request?

Comment: @LutzHorn No server is not accepting Json body,it is creating JSON for sending it in response with downloading a file

Comment: Maybe you should [edit] your question and make it more clear who is doing what. Saying that 'I' want to 'send' and 'download' something is misleading. It is not clear who is doing what.

Comment: Your code never adds `String output` or `byte[] buffer` to the response `t`.  It is hard to say what you are doing wrong if you don't show as the complete but minimal code you use and that does not work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

This would require a [`multipart/mixed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Mixed) content. Each part would have a separate content type, for example `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: i have tried multipart/mixed but its not working, is is not identifying json part as well as application/octet-stream part

Comment: Lutz is right, an http request can only have one request and one response. The way around this limitation is the multipart but if it's not properly supported, how would you expect it to guess what is what without a multipart container ?